# Arraylist read from file outputs twice

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList of items - name, account number and balance read from a .txt file. Why is the output twice? (I've only 4 lines in my file each containing-  name; account number; balance)
[image]

I want things above blue line only. Why is it displaying twice?

This is my class  to retrieve from file and print

```
class BankAccount{ //core banking facilities
PrintStream pw=System.out;
protected String name;
protected long accountNumber;
protected float balance=0;
public String choiceList="\n1.AddAccount\n2.Withdraw\n3.Deposit\n4.MyAccount";

public BankAccount(String name,long accountNumber,float balance){
    this.accountNumber=accountNumber;
    this.name=name;
    this.balance = balance; 
 }
 public String getName(){
    return this.name;
 }
 public long get_Account_no(){
    return this.accountNumber;
 }
 public float get_Balance(){
    return this.balance;
 }

public BankAccount(){//loads from file to arraylist
        BufferedReader in = null;
        ArrayList <BankAccount> customer_list=new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
            try {   
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bankfile.txt"));
            String str;
                while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] temp_list=str.split(";");
                    accountNumber=Long.parseLong(temp_list[1]);
                    balance=Float.parseFloat(temp_list[2]);
                    BankAccount customer = new BankAccount(temp_list[0],accountNumber,balance);
                    customer_list.add(customer);
                }
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
            try{ in.close();
            } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
         }
    }
    for(BankAccount c: customer_list) pw.println(c.getName()+" "+c.get_Balance()+"\n");
}
```

}
and my main is-

```
class banker {
public static void main(String args[]){
    additional_functionality af=new additional_functionality();
    BankAccount ba=new BankAccount();
    ba.pw.println("This is.. \n \t\tTHE BANK\nplease wait...");
    String ch=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(ba.choiceList);
    Integer choice=Integer.parseInt(ch);
    switch(choice){
        case 1: af.addAcount();
                break;
        case 4: //af.findAccount();
                break;
        default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Choice!","ERR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }System.exit(0);
```

}

my text file is-

[bankfile.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElGfr.png)

Comment: Can you show your txt file?

Comment: Please add the full source code to your question.

Comment: @Progman Please ignore the **additional_functionality** class which inherits the **BankAccount** class.

Comment: @KumarPrateekViraj Please include the remaining source code, including the `additional_functionarlity` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, i'm not getting error. Hope this will helps you.  I think that problem is that you twice run this constructor. Also, I run your code. And it's works.

My **Main.java**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code
    new BankAccount();
}
}
```

My file **bankfile.txt**

```
lala;0;0
coca;0;1
bola;1;1
```

My **BankAccount.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BankAccount {

private  String name;
private  long accountNumber;
private  float balance;

public BankAccount(){//loads from file to arraylist
    BufferedReader in = null;
    ArrayList<BankAccount> customer_list=new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bankfile.txt"));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] temp_list=str.split(";");
            accountNumber=Long.parseLong(temp_list[1]);
            balance=Float.parseFloat(temp_list[2]);
            BankAccount customer = new BankAccount(temp_list[0],accountNumber,balance);
            customer_list.add(customer);
        }
        for(BankAccount c: customer_list) System.out.println(c.getName()+" "+c.get_Balance());
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try{ in.close();
            } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
}
 public BankAccount(String name, Long accountNumber, float balance){
    this.name = name;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
 }

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public long getAccountNumber() {
    return accountNumber;
}

public float get_Balance() {
    return balance;
}
}
```

Comment: I cannot figure out whether it is due to the while loop or the constructor running twice (if it is).

Comment: Try to put breakpoint on line with construcror that reads from file and RUN debbuger on (IntelijIdea or else). This will show then it's calling.

Comment: Thanks @Mykhailo Voloshyn. The constructor was being invoked twice.
due to this-  ` BankAccount ba=new BankAccount() `